# Describe call returns fields that error in SOQL

Tags: soql, describesobject, describefieldresult

The describe call is returning a bunch of fields on Account such as BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude, PhotoUrl, etc that result in the following error when included in SOQL queries:

> No such column 'BillingLongitude' on entity 'Account'. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

The describe code is in PKG1 while the query is in PKG2. The 2 packages are installed in a client org and don't seem to mix well with each other. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the API versions of each. If they don't match, you'll get errors on fields that don't exist in the corresponding API version. The most famous incident of this was the [LastViewedDate Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC). Do not rely on dynamic SOQL strings working between API versions, or you'll be be in for some unpleasant surprises.

Comment: I can tell right away that's the reason. Thank you.